# Kotlin - Transform value at initialisation

Tags: kotlin

i'm new in kotlin and i want to know if we can transform a content value at initialisation : with this example :

```
@Document
data class Category(
    @Id val id: Id? = null,
    val label: String
)
```

Category is a document (entity for mongodb) and when i'm instanciating this object, i want to transform label property in uppercase. How can i do that to stay idiomatic with the language ? The point is to keep the immutable properties of the `val` keyword.

```
val categ = Category(label = "Test")
println(categ.label) // --> TEST
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can encapsulate the "upperCasing" into a factory:

```
data class Category constructor(val label: String) {

    init {
        if (label != label.toUpperCase()) {
            throw IllegalStateException("Label must be uppercase")
        }
    }

    companion object {
        fun createInstance(str: String) = Category(str.toUpperCase())
    }

}
```

The `init` block ensures, that clients don't create unwanted instances with non-upper labels (which should be documented).

Create an instance like this:

`val instance = Category.createInstance("xy")`

You might want to make explicit that you do transformations if the parameter is not upper case already by naming the factory accordingly, e.g. `withTransformedLabel` or simply add some documentation ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to **s1m0nw1**'s solution, an alternative approach may be to use a private primary constructor and a secondary public constructor, which functions the same but has a slightly different signature to avoid conflict. This can be particularly useful when a public constructor is necessary. Below is an implementation example for your specific case:

```kotlin
@Document
data class Category private constructor(
    @Id val id: Id?,
    val label: String,
) {
    constructor(
        id: Id? = null,
        label: CharSequence,
    ) : this(id, label.toString().uppercase())
}
```

This approach also works for value classes. However, do note that both this solution and the one by s1m0nw1 can be bypassed by the `copy()` method generated for data classes.